# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy' but kivy is installed in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, kivy

I'm running Windows 10, Python 3.8.5, kviy:
PS C:\Users\Zachs_Flex_5> pip -V
pip 20.2.3 from c:\users\zachs_flex_5\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)

I don't understand what I did wrong

**Code:**

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import app
from kivy.uix.widget import widget


class MyGrid(Widget):
    pass


class Main(Widget):
    def build(self):
        return Main()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main().run()
```

name and main above have double underscore before and after

**Error Message:**

> PS C:\Users\Zachs_Flex_5> &
> C:/Users/Zachs_Flex_5/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe
> c:/Users/Zachs_Flex_5/Documents/Main.py
> /python.exe c:/Users/Zachs_Flex_5 Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:/Users/Zachs_Flex_5/Documents/Main.py", line 1, in 
> import kivy ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy'

Comment: See [kivy.org](https://kivy.org/#download). "Python 2.7 and 3.5 to 3.7 is supported."  Note that python 3.8 is not listed as supported.

Comment: @JohnAnderson Okay, now my VSCode says Python 3.7.9, but when i check the version in the terminal it displays, >>> python -V
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'python' is not defined

Comment: Also, the Python extension is still in the recommended section and not in the enabled section. When I click on it it says enable though. The bottom left is where is says Python 3.7.9.

Comment: @Zach Harrison This is because you execute the command "python -v" in the python interactive window, you can use "exit()" to exit.

Comment: @JillCheng ok, now it returns Python 3.8.5 and the bottom left corner still displays Python 3.7.9. So I deleted Python 3.8.5 from my PC, now it returns an error: python : The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script 
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,      
verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: @Zach Harrison When you delete python3.8.5, the terminal cannot find it. It is recommended that you restart your computer to make the system aware that python3.8.5 is no longer available.